# What's the reference dB level in a spectrum analyser?

Tags: switching, spectrum-analyzer, decibel, spectrum

I am using a spectrum analyser to measure the 248kHz buck switching frequency and its harmonics in my board. I have set the frequency range from 200kHz and 1MHz and I am using a near field H-probe.

When I give peak search on the spectrum analyser, I get a peak at the 248kHz frequency with an amplitude of 40dB.  When I change the amplitude level in voltage, I get -14dBmV.

I also get other harmonics, too.

I just want to understand two things:

1. I know the dB is just the ratio of two quantities (power or voltage.) When I get 40dB and -14dBmV, what is the reference level that is taken by the spectrum analyser which it compares with the output power? I assume the spectrum analyser takes a reference voltage or power level and compares it with my board output level and then only it provides the value of 40dB and -14dBmV. Am I correct?
2. What does the +ve and -ve dB value signify in electrical terms?

Please understand that I am just starting the learn the uses and the operation of spectrum analyser. Would be glad if someone could help with the answers in simpler terms.

Edit :

Please find the attached image from this [AppNote](https://www.keysight.com/upload/cmc_upload/All/PPT1_AGILENT_les-bases-de-l-analyse-de-spectre.pdf) from Keysight

[image]

The image shows a reference level set at the top. How is this value chosen and on what basis?

Comment: "dBmV" means the reference level is 1 mV (rms, I believe).

Comment: Can you share a screen shot showing where you're seeing "dB" and where "dBmV"?

Comment: the Reference Level  may depend on attenuators you select to protect the input diode mixer of the Spectrum Analyzer. In older SA, you had to find that setting, and perform add/subtract. On computerized SA, the display will show the Reference Level in dBm (0 dBm across 50 ohms is 0.223 volts rms, or 0.632 volts peakpeak)

Comment: The SA does not have a screen capture option.

Comment: So, what is my reference level then?

Comment: what is the very top left readout?

Comment: Dont know. What do you mean?

Comment: If the spectrum is showing purely dB, then it's probably doing a relative measurement between two signals. Absolute measurements in a SA are typically shown in dBm, where the reference is 1mW. If you do the math assuming 50Ω, 0dBm is equivalent to 47dBmV (reference is 1mVrms). In other words, your dBmV measurements should be 47dB higher than the dBm measurements, what is definitely not what you see.

Comment: the very top left reads "17 dBm", which is 50 milliWatts.

Comment: I was not able to get when you said 50ohms. What is 50ohms you are mentioning? And when you say relative measurement, between which two signals ?

Comment: look at your input connector. Is it labeled "50 ohms"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference level is an **absolute** power value (in dBm) that just belongs to the top of the screen.

If you change the reference level, the screen is simply vertically scrolled, but the measured curves stay the same.

All values shown in dB are displayed in relation/**relative** to the reference level.

Answer (score 0):

Reference level on a spectrum analyzer is the power level wherein all the inputs are compared for plotting on the screen. For example, if you are to plot a satellite downlink, reference level of around -65dBm may be appropriate. Wrong selection would mean that the plot will not be visible on the SA screen.

Answer (score 0):

R&S teaches for the signal of interest to be with 10dBm of the reference as shown on the picture